# Android native browser doesn't update height on overflow auto when adding elements

Tags: android, css, webkit

I'm making a 1 page mobile web app. The container is fixed at 100% height and the article inside it has

```
overflow: auto
height: 100%
```

This works great on both iOS and Android, the viewport stays static and the content scrolls in the middle. However, when I add a new DOM element to the article, or unhide a hidden div, Android does not update the height of the scrolling div, so any elements at the bottom of the same div will be cut off at the scroll limit.

Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK I managed to fix this by forcing the view to repaint whenever I altered the DOM

```
$('<style></style>').appendTo($(document.body)).remove();
```

A horrible horrible fix, but it works...

The Android browser is the new IE6.

Comment: Fixed the issues I was having in Android's Dolphin browser.  I found it worked best when wrapping it in a 100ms setTimeout, which I call on each window resize or orientationchange events.

Comment: @GreeenGiant I'd have hugged you if you were here :D

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue when having `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` set on the scrolling `div` to tweak hardware acceleration on iOS. Removing that fixed the scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

I've used following approach:

```
$('#my_di').addClass('dummy').removeClass('dummy');
```